# Unauthorized message while trying to make requests to Filtered stream twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am trying to make requests to [Filtered stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream#tab1) Twitter API service by using the following code:

```
def filtered_stream(token):

    'token input is the Bearer Token'
    
    # endpoint URL
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?'
        
    # parameters
    params = { 
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
        'tweet.fields': 'created_at'
    }
    
    res = requests.get(url = url, params = params, stream=True)
    response = res.json()
    
    return response
```

But I am getting the following response:

```
{'title': 'Unauthorized',
 'type': 'about:blank',
 'status': 401,
 'detail': 'Unauthorized'}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that error. My app belongs to a project which makes it available to make request with V2. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here is a rewrite of a code sample that hopefully makes this easier to follow.

```
import requests
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class TwitterStream:
    bearer_token: str = "<YOUR BEARER TOKEN GOES HERE>"

    @classmethod
    def bearer_oauth(cls, request_object):
        """
        Method used to authenticated get requests made to the api.
        :param request_object: requests object, used to specify headers for authentication.
        :return request_object: same object with bearer token and app identifiable user agent string.
        """

        request_object.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {}".format(cls.bearer_token)
        request_object.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2FilteredStreamPython"
        return request_object

    @classmethod
    def get_rules(cls):
        """ "
        Specify rules for searching the streams.
        :return json_response: JSON, API response that contains the rules to call the stream endpoint.
        """
        response = requests.get(
            "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
            auth=cls.bearer_oauth,
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(
                "Cannot get rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                    response.status_code, response.text
                )
            )
        json_response = response.json()
        return json_response

    @classmethod
    def delete_all_rules(cls, rules):
        """
        Deletes existing rules.
        :param rules: json response, rules returned from get rules method above.
        """

        if rules or "data" in rules:
            ids = list(map(lambda rule: rule["id"], rules["data"]))
            payload = {"delete": {"ids": ids}}
            response = requests.post(
                "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
                auth=cls.bearer_oauth,
                json=payload,
            )
            if response.status_code != 200:
                raise Exception(
                    "Cannot delete rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                        response.status_code, response.text
                    )
                )

    @classmethod
    def set_rules(cls, rules):
        """
        Sets rules for calling the stream endpoint.
        :param rules: list of dicts containing rules. Sample syntax:
        [
            {"value": "dog has:images", "tag": "dog pictures"},
            {"value": "cat has:images -grumpy", "tag": "cat pictures"},
        ]
        """

        payload = {"add": rules}
        response = requests.post(
            "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
            auth=cls.bearer_oauth,
            json=payload,
        )
        if response.status_code != 201:
            raise Exception(
                "Cannot add rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                    response.status_code, response.text
                )
            )

    @classmethod
    def get_stream(cls, breaker):
        """
        Call the stream endpoint.
        :param breaker: int, number of successful calls to make to the stream endpoint.
        :return json_responses: list of json reponses.
        """
        response = requests.get(
            "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream",
            auth=cls.bearer_oauth,
            stream=True,
        )
        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(
                "Cannot get stream (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                    response.status_code, response.text
                )
            )

        count = 0
        json_responses = []
        for response_line in response.iter_lines():
            if response_line:
                json_response = json.loads(response_line)
                json_responses.append(json_response)
                count += 1
            if count == breaker:
                break

        if json_responses:
            return json_responses
        else:
            raise Exception(
                "No responses returned from stream ({}".format(
                    [x for x in response.iter_lines()]
                )
            )

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, my_rules, breaker):
        """
        Main function for calling the endpoint.
        :param my_rules: list of dicts containing rules. Sample syntax:
        [
            {"value": "dog has:images", "tag": "dog pictures"},
            {"value": "cat has:images -grumpy", "tag": "cat pictures"},
        ]
        :param breaker: int, number of successful calls to make to the stream endpoint.
        :return: output, list of json responses. Note the code will raise an error if no ouptut as defined in the above
        method.
        """
        existing_rules = cls.get_rules()
        cls.delete_all_rules(rules=existing_rules)
        cls.set_rules(rules=my_rules)
        output = cls.get_stream(breaker=breaker)
        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TwitterStream = TwitterStream()
    result = TwitterStream.main(my_rules=[
            {"value": "dog has:images", "tag": "dog pictures"},
            {"value": "cat has:images -grumpy", "tag": "cat pictures"},
        ], breaker=3)
```

I think the syntax for how you're making requests to the API is wrong - have a look at their sample code [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py) for this endpoint.

I'm not too sure what you're trying to do so it's tricky to be more specific but I'd start by pasting their sample code and using your bearer token.

Comment: Yes but it is very confusing. Some functions receive parameters that are not defined.

Comment: what exact functions are receiving parameters that are not defined, please? You could also raise this as an issue on the GitHub samples.

Comment: @AndyPiper I think most functions have this problem. Actually, if you check the message under the main button it says that all checks have failed because of the first function (which I think is the most important).

Comment: @brenda ah sorry I missed that. The code is weirdly terrible. I just added a quick rewrite in an edit to my answer, let me know if it helps.